# 'People can be trapped in their cars' means...?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I've got a paragraph and a question following:

> ...Snow can cause damage too. It can cave in the roof of a building. A
>   heavy snowstorm can delay airplane flights and cause automobile
>   accidents. Farm animals sometimes die in snowstorms, and when country
>   roads are closed by the snow, people can be trapped in their cars and
>   freeze to death...

In the passage, "people can be trapped in their cars" means:

```
a. they are caught in a trap
b. they are stuck in their cars
c. they can't go out of their cars and drive away
d. all are correct
```

The dictionary tells that a 'trap' is 'an unpleasant or difficult situation'. Therefore, I choose d. since all answers seem to be correct. However, the solution is only c without further explanation.

Could you explain why the solution is c. in this question?

Comment: They are not caught in a trap but in their cars. If they get out of their cars, they can't drive away. So, the logical answer is b.

Comment: What JayHook said: C makes no sense, since if you get out of your car, you're on foot, and - unless you're some strange species of Transformer - you can't *drive* anywhere if you're on foot. Basically, this sounds like a badly-written quiz question.

Comment: Well, it has to be (b), since the above comments rule out (a) and (c). But it's a rather pointless question, given that in this context, ***stuck*** is simply a synonym for ***trapped***. doquan0 - you haven't really found the relevant definition for *trapped* here, where it means *caught, snared, held fast, unable to move freely* (i.e. - the people are unable to continue moving along on their journey). I think this is General Reference, but that's all history now.

Comment: It's also worth noting that there's a difference between **a** trap and a situation in which you are trapped. Trap as a noun implies an intentional snare, something that was set up specifically to trap(v.) something/body else. The usage of _trap_ as a noun is what immediately eliminates option (a), despite them indeed being trapped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would have picked (b) as well, but I think I can see what the quiz designers were trying to say.

First, what [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/trap_17) says about the word *trap*:

> **trap** (*v.*) to prevent someone from leaving a place, especially a dangerous place : *Both men were trapped inside the burning car*.

In the snow, however, people aren't usually trapped inside the car. The driver and passengers can freely get out and walk around, but the *car* is unable to move, usually because the tires can't get sufficient traction. The situation looks something like this:

[image: car stuck in the snow]

So, the **car** is stuck, not the people.

That said, the problem with this poorly-designed language question is this: it's very common for native English speakers to say, "Can you come pick me up? I'm stuck in the snow" even when they mean that their *vehicle* is stuck. In other words:

> I'm stuck in my car.

is a perfectly normal way to convey:

> I'm in my car, and my car is stuck.

As for people freezing to death in their cars, that's a very real danger, which is why many cold climes urge drivers to carry a [winter survival kit](http://www.dot.nd.gov/divisions/maintenance/winter-preparation.htm) in their car.

So, if the answers had been worded more like this:

> a. they are caught in a trap
>   b. they cannot get out of their cars
>   c. they can't drive away in their cars
>   d. all are correct

then I would say that answer (c) is correct. I suspect that's what the quiz designers were trying to get across, but they did as bad a job writing this question as some counties do plowing their roads.